# Change narration in the given sentence

Tags: grammar, indirect-speech, narration

The sentence is : He said ,"Get out of my way."
This question was asked in an examination. It is a standalone sentence, not constituting a part of any passage. So in this case, I do not know what exactly the context is. Depending on the situation, it could be an order or request.

Also it is not clear whether the speaker is saying these words to one people or more than one people, may be a crowd. So how are we supposed to change the narration in such cases?

Please help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "Get out of my way" without "please" sounds like an order to me! I'm not sure what 'change the narration' means, though. You could change it to first person narration - "I said..."

Comment: @KateBunting By 'change of narration' I mean changing the direct speech into indirect or reported speech.

Comment: [correction: one person, two people]

Comment: If no context is given you would have to choose what pronoun to use - "He told me/her/them to get out of his way". I don't see that any one could be said to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The man asked for his way to be cleared.

... would be one way of saying this in indirect or reported speech, and without identifying the 'audience' for the 'way clearing' as being one, or many, people.